# How to calculate sum of two event till the condition breaks in Python? I am new to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, python-requests

Example:
I want to find Deviation of a vehicles:
Deviation defination:

Driving more than 4 hours without a break of at least 1 hour in total. The break of 1 hour can be divided into breaks of 15 minutes each. Any break of less than 15 minutes will not be counted as a break.
Transit = Vehicle is running
& Stop = break

To count deviation:
Each hour of continuous driving beyond 4 hours will be counted as 1 instance. E.g. if the vehicle drives for 5 hours and 2 minutes at a stretch then the count will be 2 (5th hour and the 2 minutes of 6th hour)

Unable to build this logic.

following is the toy data link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oWl6_k5KxTkztKAaYb6nO2PcI3gBs2RH/view?usp=sharing

I have tried this but no:

```
out['StartDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(out['StartDate'].dt.date.astype(str)+ ' '+ out['StartTime'].astype(str))
out['EndDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(out['EndDate'].dt.date.astype(str)+ ' '+ out['EndTime'].astype(str))
out['Duration'] =  (out['EndDateTime'] - out['StartDateTime']).astype('timedelta64[m]')

itr = 0
run = 0
stop = 0
dfg = out.groupby(['companyid','Vehicle'])
df_newout = pd.DataFrame()
while itr in (enumerate(out)):
    
         
    if run < 240 & stop < 60:
         run = out[out['EventType'] == 'Transit']['Duration'].sum()
         stop = out[out['EventType'] == 'Stop']['Duration'].sum()
         run.append(itr)
         stop.append(itr)
       
        
itr = itr+1
```

I am reposting this because I am still lagging and I didn't get any support yet!
Please help!

Comment: Please a) edit a minimal sample of data into your question perhaps as python variable initialisation, and b) revise your code to load this data. Then show the output your code produces from this data and explain what’s wrong with it. Your code should be a [mre] that I can paste into a file and run to see the same results you put in the question.

Comment: You don’t need to increment `itr` - have you tried simple prnting the values (for example `itr`) your code is operating on at each iteration of the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the full logic of what you are looking for, but it should get you started.

Key steps:

- Convert start\stop times to duration
- Convert all short stops to Transit
- For each transit row, check the following period until total transit is 4 hours
- For each period, compare transit and stop values for deviation

Input format for reference:

```
companyid,Vehicle,EventType,StartDate,StartTime,EndDate,EndTime
236,Vehicle2,Stop ,8/29/2020,0:25,8/29/2020,0:26
236,Vehicle2,Transit,8/29/2020,0:26,8/29/2020,0:33
236,Vehicle2,Stop ,8/29/2020,0:33,8/29/2020,0:33
236,Vehicle2,Transit,8/29/2020,0:33,8/29/2020,0:34
236,Vehicle2,Stop ,8/29/2020,0:34,8/29/2020,0:34
```

I only wrote code for vehicle1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.options.display.max_rows = 500

out = pd.read_csv('toydata.csv')
print(out.columns)
out = out[out['Vehicle']=='Vehicle1'] # only first vehicle for now

out['StartDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(out['StartDate'] + ' '+ out['StartTime'])
out['EndDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(out['EndDate'] + ' '+ out['EndTime'])
out['Duration'] =  (out['EndDateTime'] - out['StartDateTime']).astype('timedelta64[m]')

print(out.head(100))

# all short breaks, convert to transit 
out['EventType'] = out.apply(lambda x: 'Transit' if x['Duration'] < 15 or x['EventType'] == 'Transit' else 'Stop', axis=1)

periods = {}  # key is drive start time

def CheckDeviation(endtime):
   for p in periods.values():
      if p['deviation'] == None:
          if p['transit'] >= 240:  # 4 hours
              if p['stop'] >= 60: # 1 hour
                 p['deviation'] = False  # enough rest
                 p['endtime'] = endtime  # end of period
              else:
                 p['deviation'] = True  # not enough rest
                 p['endtime'] = endtime  # end of period
             

for index, r in out.iterrows():
   if r['EventType'] == 'Transit':
       # add to existing periods
       for p in periods.values():
           if p['deviation'] == None:  # period in progress
                p['transit'] += r['Duration']
       periods[r['StartDateTime']] = {'transit':r['Duration'], 'stop':0, 'endtime': None, 'deviation': None}
   else:  # stop
       for p in periods.values():
          if p['deviation'] == None:  # period in progress
             p['stop'] += r['Duration']  # add to stop time
   CheckDeviation(r['EndDateTime'])
    
# end of trip, no deviation for remaining periods
for p in periods.values():
  if p['deviation'] == None:
      p['deviation'] = False
   
df = pd.DataFrame(periods)
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['transit','stop','endtime','deviation'], aggfunc=np.sum)
print(pvt)
```

Output (truncated). The first column is the start time for the period.

```
                    deviation              endtime  stop transit
2020-08-29 05:43:00     False  2020-08-29 12:51:00   178     250
2020-08-29 05:50:00     False  2020-08-29 12:51:00   178     243
2020-08-29 05:51:00     False  2020-08-29 12:51:00   178     242
2020-08-29 06:10:00     False  2020-08-29 13:44:00   211     243
2020-08-29 06:12:00     False  2020-08-29 13:44:00   211     241
2020-08-29 06:36:00     False  2020-08-29 14:07:00   211     240
2020-08-29 06:48:00     False  2020-08-29 14:25:00   211     246
2020-08-29 06:49:00     False  2020-08-29 14:25:00   211     245
2020-08-29 06:50:00     False  2020-08-29 14:25:00   211     244
```

Comment: thanks let me check and also have you excluded breaks which are < 15mins?

Comment: What is periods dataframe? NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-dee58c557e5d> in <module>
     21        periods[r['StartDateTime']] = {'transit':r['Duration'], 'stop':0, 'endtime': None, 'deviation': None}
     22    else:  # stop
---> 23        for p in periods.values():
     24           if p['deviation'] == None:  # period in progress
     25              p['stop'] += r['Duration']  # add to stop time

NameError: name 'periods' is not defined

Comment: Short (less than 15 minute) stops are converted to Transit. Every Transit entry starts a new period. You could merge all sequential Transit entries together before processing.

Comment: @ I have dataframe out that I have shared and I just copy pasted your code then what I suppose to do? Why I am getting this error?